# Iron router meteor auto unsubscribe?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

When using iron router to change to different template(pages), does it auto unsubscribe collection that no longer required ? Below scenario explain the question

1. on page1,  we call Meteor.subscribe(document, id)
2. iron router change to page 2
3. on page 2 , we call Meteor.subscribe(document,id2) ,  does step 1 auto unsubscribe ?

Comment: Yes, Meteor automatically unsubscribes from subscriptions ran inside a reactive computation (this is typically the case in `iron:router`), hence the creation of something like subscription manager from meteorhacks which prevents this behavior if you need to. https://meteorhacks.com/subscriptions-manager-is-here.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here:
https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/265

Iron Router/Meteor does this for you:
If you call Meteor.subscribe within a reactive computation, for example using Deps.autorun, the subscription will automatically be cancelled when the computation is invalidated or stopped;

If you wish to cache some of the subscription, see this excellent package:
https://meteorhacks.com/subscription-manager-for-iron-router.html

```
this.route('postPage', {
    path: '/post/:_id',
    template: 'postPage',
    waitOn: function() {
      return Meteor.subscribe('post', this.params._id);
    },
    cache: 5, //cache 5 blog posts
    expire: 3 //expire them if inactive for 3 minutes
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you return the handle (or an array containing the handle) to the subscription in the route's `waitOn` function, iron router will unsubscribe for you.