# How do I unsubscribe from the subscription set by Iron Router's waitOn?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have a list of items fetched from a collection and I want to make it show different stuff depending what button is clicked. I figured I'd do this via sessions that update the publication.

Here's my publication:

```
Meteor.publish('stuff', function(filter) {
  var nameVar = filter || "default"
  return myStuff.find({name: nameVar})
})
```

Which I subscribe to in my router:

```
Router.route('/', {
  name: 'home',
  layoutTemplate: 'homeLayout',
  waitOn: function() {
    return Meteor.subscribe('stuff', Session.get('filter'));
  }
});
```

Then make the buttons do their thing (they each have an id that matches what I want to filter by):

```
Template.buttonFilter.events({
  'click button': function(event, template) {
    var buttonId = event.currentTarget.id
    Meteor.subscribe('stuff', Session.set('filter', buttonId))
  }
})
```

However, when I click a button it won't unsubscribe from what I first subscribed to via the router, only from what was set on my last button click. I don't really understand why or how to fix it.

**Edit:** I don't believe this to be a duplicate since the answers to the other questions talk about changing routes, which I'm not doing.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iron router meteor auto unsubscribe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25995399/iron-router-meteor-auto-unsubscribe)

Comment: Since those answers didn't answer my question, I don't think so.

Comment: Good point, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like what you want (correct me if I'm wrong) is not so much to unsubscribe from the prior search, but to *reactively* subscribe to the current search and drop all records that are not encompassed by it. If so, you don't need to manually manage unsubscribing - Meteor will do that for you; you just need to make your subscription reactive.

Iron Router's `waitOn` will not rerun each time the subscription changes. To do that there are a few options. The quick and dirty option is to move the subscription from `waitOn` to `onBeforeAction` which will be rerun each time:

```
Router.route('/', {
  name: 'home',
  layoutTemplate: 'homeLayout',
  onBeforeAction: function() {
    Meteor.subscribe('stuff', Session.get('filter'));
    this.next(); //make sure to include
  }
});
```

Alternatively you can do it outside the router:

```
Tracker.autorun(function(){
  var filter = Session.get('filter');
  Meteor.subscribe('stuff', filter);
});
```

In either case you don't need to change the subscription from template.events - just change the session value.

```
Template.buttonFilter.events({
  'click button': function(event, template) {
    var buttonId = event.currentTarget.id;
    Session.set('filter', buttonId);
  }
});
```